# Enable wifi monitor mode on Samsung Chromebook

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I want to buy the Samsung Chromebook and use it with Ubuntu (12.10).

I also want to play around with airmon-ng and thus want to use the wifi card in monitor mode.

I didn't find any information if the samsung wifi card and the driver support monitor mode.

Does anybody know if monitor mode on the Chromebook is possible?

#### Technical Details

The Laptop is called XE303C12-A01US ([Samsung Website](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/chrome-os-devices/XE303C12-A01US))

Wifi Chip is an Atheros AR9382 802.11n Wi-Fi chip with XSPAN ([Link to iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung-Series-5-3G-Chromebook-Teardown/5939/2))

Answer (score 1):

The picture [here](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Mobile-and-Wireless/Samsung-Series-5-Chromebook-Teardown-Reveals-Spartan-Efficient-Design-314084/) shows a chipset number that is shown as supported by ath9k [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k). Generally atheros cards that are supported at all support monitor mode.

As always, when you don't provide a specific wireless chipset/specific chromebook model and say "a chromebook" it's nearly impossible to answer your question.

It's not exactly analogous to "If I buy a Dell will the wireless work?", but it's in the same ballpark.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I added the model name and the wifi chipset.

Comment: The 9382 is the same one that is cited in the answer, so the answer is "should work, but you have to try it unless you find someone that owns one"